# Infinite scrolling inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap, nginfinitescroll

I want to make an infinite scroll inside an [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) modal.

I want also to fix the modal header and modal footer and only scroll on what's inside the modal body. I'm using the [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/index.html) library.

The problem is that it's showing two scroll bars and the outer bar is controlling the infinite scroll.

JS:

```
app.controller('DealCommentsCtrl', function ($scope, $location, callingDealData) {
  if(!callingDealData.getDeal()){
    $location.path('/deals');
  }else{
    $scope.comments = [];
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
      $scope.comments.push(COMMENTS[i]);
    }
  }

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var last = $scope.comments.length;
    for(var i = last; i <= last + 6; i++) {
      $scope.comments.push(COMMENTS[i]);
    }
  };
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal mymodal" ng-controller="DealCommentsCtrl">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Comments</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
              <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
                {{comment.text}}<br/>
                {{comment.userFullName}}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button ng-click="$hide();" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mE5EMEYV6Tx3S1VopKfW 
But the scrolling doesn't work because the main page have no scrolling (I think it comes to the same issue)

Thanks